# BreezeJS lookup data fails locally

Tags: breeze

I have a breeze web api controller with a lookups which returns different datasets of users. This works fine for a remote query but not for a local query where the first dataset is always chosen. My WebAPI controller:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<object> Lookups()
    {
        var currentUser = await UserManager.FindById(Guid.Parse(User.Identity.GetUserId()));
        var companyId = currentUser.CompanyId.Value;
        return new
        {
            allUsersInCompany = UnitOfWork.UserRepository.Get(u => u.CompanyId == companyId && u.Enabled == true).Select(v => new User()
            {
                Id = v.Id,
                FirstName = v.FirstName,
                LastName = v.LastName,
            }),
            assessors = UnitOfWork.UserRepository.Get(u => u.CompanyId == companyId && u.Enabled == true && u.Id != currentUser.Id &&
            (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(u.StId) || u.UserRoles.Any(ur => ur.Role.Description == "Assessor"))
            ).Select(v => new User()
                {
                    Id = v.Id,
                    FirstName = v.FirstName,
                    LastName = v.LastName,
                    Town = v.Town,
                    Postcode = v.Postcode
                })
        };
    }
```

I then rebuild the data from local storage on the client using:

```
data = store.getItem("EmCache");
modelService.configureMetadataStore(em.metadataStore); }
em.importEntities(data);
_lookups = [{
    allUsersInCompany: em.executeQueryLocally(_lookupsQuery.toType(em.metadataStore.getEntityType("User"))),
    assessors: em.executeQueryLocally(_lookupsQuery.toType(em.metadataStore.getEntityType("User")))
}];
```

The problem is, is that both assessors and allUsersInCompany are set to the data for allUsersInCompany when I execute the query locally. Is there any way to pull out the right data for each part of the lookup query?

Answer (score 0):

Your queries are mapping them to the same type -

```
allUsersInCompany: em.executeQueryLocally(_lookupsQuery.toType(em.metadataStore.getEntityType("User"))),
assessors: em.executeQueryLocally(_lookupsQuery.toType(em.metadataStore.getEntityType("User")))
```

of `User` which is probably why it is grabbing the same data.  I am not sure what the entity type is for the `Assessors` but if that is what they are called in the DB try changing it to something like -

```
allUsersInCompany: em.executeQueryLocally(_lookupsQuery.toType(em.metadataStore.getEntityType("User"))),
assessors: em.executeQueryLocally(_lookupsQuery.toType(em.metadataStore.getEntityType("Assessor")))
```

Comment: Both Assessors and all users in company are of the type user, they just contain different data.

Comment: What differentiates an Assessor from a User?  Is there a flag or something?  If you were writing a SQL or Linq query you would have to have some way of identifying them, same thing with Breeze's querying

Comment: An assessor is a user, what differentiates them is that all users and assessors contains different data